# Does anyone know of a public GitHub project that has Twilio integration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms, twilio

I am trying to integrate Twilio SMS with my Rails application, but I could use some direction.
It would be great to view some code samples of how other people have accomplished this. Any content you can recommend would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The twilio-ruby gem has worked great for us.  The specifics on how you do it depend on your requirements, but as a quick and dirty example to send a text notification after a new blog post is created:

In Gemfile

```
gem 'twilio-ruby', require: 'twilio-ruby'
```

In app/models/post.rb

```
class Post
  ADMIN_NUMBER = '555-1212'
  TWILIO_PHONE = '555-2121'

  belongs_to :user
  after_create :send_notification!

  def send_notification!
    # ideally tokens should not be in version control, stored on an external file and pulled in here
    account_sid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    auth_token = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'

    # set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
    @client.account.messages.create(
      :from => TWILIO_PHONE,
      :to => ADMIN_NUMBER,
      :body => "Post created by #{user.email}"
    )
  end

end
```

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/02/twilio-on-rails-integrating-twilio-with-your-rails-4-app.html)? It has its source code [here on github](https://github.com/crabasa/twilio-rails-4).

You could also use this [search](https://github.com/search?q=%22gem%20%27twilio-ruby%27%22&ref=cmdform&type=Code) on github.

Comment: I have tried the tutorial, but I have not yet checked out the source code. Thanks!